# Request method 'DELETE' not supported

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I started learning Spring boot and am trying to make a simple REST service for implementing CRUD operations on employee records. But I am getting this error while executing the DELETE method-

> {
>      "timestamp": "2018-08-10T11:17:47.619+0000",
>      "status": 405,
>       "error": "Method Not Allowed",
>       "message": "Request method 'DELETE' not supported",
>       "path": "/employees/123"
>   }

My Controller-

```
@DeleteMapping("/employee/{id}")
public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable int id) {
    return employeeService.deleteEmployee(id);

}
```

My Service-

```
public String deleteEmployee(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
        if(list.get(i).getId()==id) {
            list.remove(i);
        }
    }
    return "Employee withh id "+id+" has been removed from the company";
}
```

Comment: How are you making the call?

Comment: So this is a simple typo then, voting to close

Comment: A typo: You have `employee` in the mapping but you call `employees`.

Answer (score 16):

In the output you pasted the path is `/employees/123` which does not match your `@DeleteMapping("/employee/{id}")`.

Comment: Nice attention!

Comment: @cst1992: Although correct, this answer is highly overrated. It's sad to see high quality and detailed answers to remain ignored while answers correcting a typo are upvoted to skies.